# How to solve equations with absolute value on both sides?

Tags: absolute-value

Assume we are given an equation $|f(x)|$=g(x). From the definition of the absolute value we know that:$$
|f(x)|= \begin{cases} +f(x), & \mbox{if } f(x) \geq 0 \\ -f(x), & \mbox{if } f(x)<0 \end{cases}
$$
This implies that in order to solve it we need to consider two cases, namely when $f(x) \geq0$ and $f(x) < 0$. In the first one, for instance, we have $f(x)=g(x)$. We obtain some solutions, but shall we keep only these $x$'s that make $f(x) \geq 0$? It seems logical. In my class however, we solved problems like that one simply by making an alternative, i.e. $$
f(x)=g(x) \vee f(x)=-g(x)
$$
without checking if $x$ from the first "case" makes $f(x)$ bigger or equal zero, and if $x$ form the second one makes $f(x)$ smaller than zero. That really baffles me...
Also, how do you solve $|f(x)|=|g(x)|$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move right side to the left and now you have absolute values only on one side :D

Comment: Squaring both sides of $|f(x)|=|g(x)|$ gives us $[f(x)]^2=[g(x)]^2$. This may be useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering, guys, but I still don't know how to deal with the problem in the 1st part of the question :(

Comment: Here, for example equation of the form |f(x)|=g(x) was solved in multiple cases. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955061/equation-with-double-absolute-value

Comment: @AleksyBałaziński: I understand your confusion, we do need to add condition $g(x) \ge 0$ for the first case. It will help you to avoid fake solutions. It's a good practice to consider domain of the equation from the start.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you all for answering my question. That's my summary. 
Equation $|f(x)|=g(x)$ is equivalent to: $$
f(x)=g(x) \mbox{ if } f(x) \geq 0
$$ and $$
f(x)=-g(x) \mbox{ if } f(x)<0.
$$
Because $g(x)$ can take any value (it has't been specified) we have to check if the solutions obtained in above cases make function $f$ greater or equal to zero or less than zero, respectively. If, however, function $g$ is defined in such way that $$
\forall g(x) \geq 0
$$
there is no need to check whether the obtained solutions are in appropriate intervals - that is because the only place when two functions ($|f| \mbox{ and } g$) can meet lays *above* the $x$-axis. Thus if $\forall g(x) \geq 0$ then the equation $|f(x)|=g(x)$ simplifies into an alternative: $$
f(x)=g(x) \vee f(x)=-g(x). 
$$
The same, of course, holds if $g(x)=c$, where $c$ is some constant and $c \geq 0$. Then we have $$
f(x)=c \vee f(x)=-c.
$$
If $c<0$ no solutions exist.

Answer (score 0):

To your last question:
$$|f(x)|=|g(x)|$$ squaring this equation and using that $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$ we get
$$(f(x)-g(x))(f(x)+g(x))=0$$

Comment: Doesn't this still lead to the statement $f(x) = \pm g(x)$? Or did you aim to give a proof of this fact?

Comment: The proof of this statement can you read in my post!

Comment: Ok, so the aim of your post was to give a proof of the statement $|f(x)| = |g(x)| \implies f(x) = \pm g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, indeed, this have i written.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is simply equivalent to
$$f(x)=\pm g(x)  \;\textbf{ and } \;g(x)\ge 0.$$
The second is, even more simply, equivalent to $$f(x)=\pm g(x).$$

Comment: Ok, that's what I've been told about. However f(x)=+g(x) only when f(x) is bigger or equal zero. So if, somehow, we get solution x=a, and f(a) is less than zero we should say that a is not the solution for the equation. In your method (and simultaneously my teacher's) we don't check anything... Is there a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Are you mentioning the first or the second equation?

Comment: The first one, absolute value only on f(x)

Comment: Well if you have a solution $a$ of the *system*, as $(a)\ge 0$, $f(a)$ can't be negative. That's why there's noting to check.

Comment: If a=2 and f(x)=-x, then f(a)=-2 which is obviously less than zero. I found a question where someone had problem analogous to mine which was solved using multiple cases. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955061/equation-with-double-absolute-value

Comment: Of course, but $a=2$ does not satisfy the 2nd condition: $g(a)\ge 0$, so it has to be deleted.